# Angular Bootstrap-Select timing issue to refresh

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, bootstrap-select

I love `Bootstrap-Select` and I am currently using it through the help of a directive made by another user [`joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select`](https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select) and it works as intended except when I try to fill my `<select>` element with an `$http` or in my case a `dataService` wrapper. I seem to get some timing issue, the data comes after the `selectpicker` got displayed/refreshed and then I end up having an empty Bootstrap-Select list.. though with Firebug, I do see the list of values in the now hidden `<select>`. If I then go in console and manually execute a `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh')` it then works. 
I got it temporarily working by doing a patch and adding a `.selectpicker('refresh')` inside a `$timeout` but as you know it's not ideal since we're using `jQuery` directly in an ngController...ouch!
So I believe the directive is possibly missing a watcher or at least something to trigger that the `ngModel` got changed or updated. 
Html sample code:

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <select name="language" class="form-control show-tick" 
        ng-model="vm.profile.language" 
        selectpicker data-live-search="true"
        ng-options="language.value as language.name for language in vm.languages">
    </select>
    <!-- also tried with an ng-repeat, which has the same effect -->
</div>
```

then inside my Angular Controller:

```
// get list of languages from DB
dataService
    .getLanguages()
    .then(function(data) {  
        vm.languages = data;

        // need a timeout patch to properly refresh the Bootstrap-Select selectpicker 
        // not so good to use this inside an ngController but it's the only working way I have found
        $timeout(function() {
            $('.selectpicker, select[selectpicker]').selectpicker('refresh');
        }, 1);
    });
```

and here is the directive made by (joaoneto) on [GitHub for Angular-Bootstrap-Select](https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select)

```
function selectpickerDirective($parse, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 1000,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      function refresh(newVal) {
        scope.$applyAsync(function () {
          if (attrs.ngOptions && /track by/.test(attrs.ngOptions)) element.val(newVal);
          element.selectpicker('refresh');
        });
      }

      attrs.$observe('spTheme', function (val) {
        $timeout(function () {
          element.data('selectpicker').$button.removeClass(function (i, c) {
            return (c.match(/(^|\s)?btn-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
          });
          element.selectpicker('setStyle', val);
        });
      });

      $timeout(function () {
        element.selectpicker($parse(attrs.selectpicker)());
        element.selectpicker('refresh');
      });

      if (attrs.ngModel) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, refresh, true);
      }

      if (attrs.ngDisabled) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngDisabled, refresh, true);
      }

      scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $timeout(function () {
          element.selectpicker('destroy');
        });
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: The version of AngularJS is 1.3.11

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One problem with the angular-bootstrap-select directive, is that it only watches `ngModel`, and not the object that's actually populating the options in the select. For example, if `vm.profile.language` is set to `''` by default, and `vm.languages` has a `''` option, the select won't update with the new options, because `ngModel` stays the same. I added a `selectModel` attribute to the select, and modified the angular-bootstrap-select code slightly.

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <select name="language" class="form-control show-tick" 
        ng-model="vm.profile.language" 
        select-model="vm.languages"
        selectpicker data-live-search="true"
        ng-options="language.value as language.name for language in vm.languages">
    </select>
</div>
```

Then, in the angular-bootstrap-select code, I added

```
if (attrs.selectModel) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.selectModel, refresh, true);
}
```

Now, when `vm.languages` is updated, the select will be updated too. A better method would probably be to simply detect which object should be watched by using `ngOptions`, but using this method allows for use of `ngRepeat` within a select as well.

Edit:

An alternative to using `selectModel` is automatically detecting the object to watch from `ngOptions`.

```
if (attrs.ngOptions && / in /.test(attrs.ngOptions)) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.ngOptions.split(' in ')[1], refresh, true);
}
```

Edit 2:

Rather than using the `refresh` function, you'd probably be better off just calling `element.selectpicker('refresh');` again, as you only want to actually update the value of the select when `ngModel` changes. I ran into a scenario where the list of options were being updated, and the value of the select changed, but the model didn't change, and as a result it didn't match the selectpicker. This resolved it for me:

```
if (attrs.ngOptions && / in /.test(attrs.ngOptions)) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.ngOptions.split(' in ')[1], function() {
        scope.$applyAsync(function () {
            element.selectpicker('refresh');
        });
    }, true);
}
```

Comment: Very interesting concept, this gave me the idea of using the refresh without even the need of an attribute. Since we already have the object name directly inside the `ngOptions` you could do it by only modifying the directive itself and adding something like the following: `if (attrs.ngOptions && / in /.test(attrs.ngOptions) { scope.$watch(attrs.ngOptions.split(' in ')[1], refresh, true); }` ... edit your answer with this option, or better, and I'll accept your answer... thanks a lot :)

Comment: This is a great solution for me, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is an old one... But I had to use it. This is what I added in the link(..) function of the directive:

```
            scope.$watch(
            _ => element[0].innerHTML,
            (newVal, oldVal) => {
                if (newVal !== oldVal)
                {
                    element.selectpicker('refresh');
                }
            }
            )
```